# LookbackAPI: When did user stories become unblocked?

Tags: rally

I'm running the following query to the lookback API to find stories in a date range that were unblocked, but I'm getting no results.  Am I missing something obvious?  No errors, warnings or results returned.

Below is the Generated Query I get back from the lookback API:

```
      'GeneratedQuery' => {
                            'fields' => 'true',
                            'skip' => 0,
                            'limit' => 100,
                            'find' => {
                                        '_PreviousValues.Blocked' => 'true',
                                        '_TypeHierarchy' => -51038,
                                        'Blocked' => 'false',
                                        '_ValidFrom' => {
                                                          '$lte' => '2012-11-02T04:00:00.000Z',
                                                          '$gte' => '2012-07-01T04:00:00.000Z'
                                                        }
                                      }
                          },
```

Comment: If there is something wrong, it's not jumping out at me. This query works for me: find={"Blocked":false,"_PreviousValues.Blocked":true,_TypeHierarchy:"HierarchicalRequirement"}&fields=["_PreviousValues","Blocked"]. The only difference in my case is that the I'm using _TypeHierarchy of "HierarchicalRequirement". I suspect you are entering the negative integer in your query. At one point our documentation recommended that but we've since implemented disambiguation so you can just submit "HierachicalRequirement". That said, I don't think that is the problem -51038 is correct.

Comment: Are there quotes around true or false in your original? They should be bare without the quotes. Might there be no such events for those four months? If we don't figure it out here, submit a support case and give us permission to look at your data so we can poke below the covers.

Comment: It must be something related to "Blocked" because if I pull out _PreviousValues.Blocked and Blocked I get lots of results.  If I just leave in 'Blocked' => 'false', I get nothing (so its not because I have nothing that's blocked!).  But quotes can't really be a problem-- this output is what I get back from the LookbackAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass in Boolean values, you need to make sure that they are bare true or false. If you pass them in as Strings, it will not behave as expected. Similarly for values of type Number. They should not have quotes around them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was related to "true" and "false" and the fact that I'm using Perl.

I'm using the Perl JSON library, and I didn't realize that you need to pass in JSON::true() and JSON::false() for true and false, not the literals 'true' and 'false'.  So, in effect Larry was right: it was passing "true" instead of true.

Comment: Can you mark my new answer as "accepted" so it gets the green check box and folks who find this in the future know the quick answer.